# Make Div Height 100% of Screen

Tags: html, css, dom, height

I have been reading all the 100% div height discussions and I can't find a simple solution. How can I make my div take up all of the vertical height of the screen?

Here is my code:

**css**

```
#mother {
    width:   100%;  
    margin: 0 auto; 
    z-index: 1;
}
#stripe_wrap {
    width: 1053px;
    min-height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: lime; 
}
#stripe1 {
    width: 39px;
    min-height: 500px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: #000;
    float: left;
}
#stripe2 {
    width: 39px;
    min-height: 500px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    background:#000;
    float: right;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="mother" style="overflow-x: hidden;">
    <div id="stripe_wrap">

        <div id="stripe1"></div>
        <div id="stripe2"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't get the DIV height9s) to extend to 100%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make the `<body>` tag of the height 100% as well, otherwise it is vertically truncated to fit the content.

Also make sure to put the margin of `<body>` to 0px, because otherwise it will become 100%_of_visible_area + margin, resulting in a vertical scroll bar.

Answer (score 2):

```
html, body {padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 100%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kEv8F/ - my version.

http://jsfiddle.net/kEv8F/ - your version.

Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `height:100%` for your `<body>` and `<html>`, too.
If there is nothing except this div on your page, 100% height will be 0px without these settings.