# How to make a nested div fill the rest of the height of its parent div

Tags: jquery, css, html, height

I have a hang up, but am very proud of what I have accomplished so far.  I am making an desktop style application and have successfully used css(controls width) and jquery(controls height) to expand and collapse the application per the window width and height with a min-width and min-height. Awesome right?

I can't seem to get the nested  to fill the rest of the height of the .  I know jquery is the answer as I have tried everything under the sun css.

Code bomb below. I thought you would benefit from seeing the entire structure, actually it isn't too bad yet. Thanks in advance.

HTML & JQUERY

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Test Page</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Open+Sans:400,600'    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).ready(function(){
$('#wrapper').height($(window).height()-40);
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#wrapper').height($(window).height()-40);
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="headerLeft">
            <img src="images/logo.jpg" height="60" />
        </div>
        <div id="headerRight">
            <div id="companyLinks">
                <p class="openSans">Welcome,</p> <a href="myaccount.php">Chambers and Sons Landscaping, Inc.</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
            </div>
            <div id="companyLogo">
                <img src="images/logos/1.jpg" height="60" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="contentLeft">
            <div id="contentLeftHeader">
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="contentLeftBody">
                test text<br/>
                line height test.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentRight">
            <div id="contentRightTop">
                <div id="contentRightTopHeader">
                    Header
                </div>
                <div id="contentRightTopBody">
                    test text
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="contentRightBottom">
                <div id="contentRightBottomHeader">
                    Header
                </div>
                <div id="contentRightBottomBody">
                    test text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    body{
        margin:0px;
        background-color:#cccccc;
        padding:20px;
        min-width:840px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight:normal;
        color:#4c4c4c;
        line-height:20px;
    }
    #wrapper{
        background-color:#ffffff;
        width:100%;
        min-width:800px;
        min-height:600px;
    }
    .openSans{
        margin:0px;
        display:inline;
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight:400;
        line-height:16px;
    }
    h1{
        margin:0px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size:18px;
        font-weight:600;
        line-height:24px;
    }
    #header{
        width:100%;
        margin-bottom:30px;
        overflow:auto;
    }
    #headerLeft{
        float:left;
    }
    #headerRight{
        float:right;
    }
    #companyLinks{
        margin-top:20px;
        margin-right:10px;
        float:left;
    }
    #companyLogo{
        float:left;
    }
    #header a:link{
        color:#9ad065;
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight:400;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    #header a:hover{
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    #content{
        width:100%;
    }
    #contentLeft{
        float:left;
        width:69%;
        margin-right:1%;
    }
    #contentLeftHeader{
        background-color:#9ad065;
        padding:5px;
    }
    #contentLeftBody{
        overflow:auto;
        padding:5px;
        border:2px solid #9ad065;
    }
    #contentRight{
        float:left;
        width:30%;
        background-color:#dddddd;
    }
    #contentRightTop{

    }
    #contentRightTopHeader{

    }
    #contentRightTopBody{

    }
    #contentRightBottom{

    }
    #contentRightBottomHeader{

    }
    #contentRightBottomBody{

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Div Height 100% - I'm confused!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280080/div-height-100-im-confused)

Comment: @Diodeus, thanks but I have solved that whole application scaling now I am working on a nested div.